# How to implement a tap-to-zoom animation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

When I click on an image for the first time I want to increase its scale and when I click on it again I want it to return to its original scale.

What I want is exactly like this, I found it on the Android website but I want it in Jetpack Compose:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/zoom

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library for do something like that :

[Shared Elements Transition for Jetpack Compose](https://github.com/mxalbert1996/compose-shared-elements)

with this library you can declare element with same key and use in two screen then elements show with zoom animation

hope helps you

Comment: @Fawzi Abd-Elaal is that help you ?